# How do I keep absolute positioned elements from overlapping on window resize?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

My animation script modifies the absolute position of div text elements.  I'm trying to figure out the best approach to keep the elements from overlapping on a window or text resize.  Ideally it would take on a liquid layout.

Any help that can be given is appreciated!  Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .slogan
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        width: 12em;
        margin: 0.5em;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #slogan1
    {
         position: absolute;
         left: -250px;     
         margin-right: 1em;                    
    }
    #slogan2
    {
         position: absolute;
         left: -250px; 
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = slideRight;

    function slideRight() {                  
        //code that slides slogan1 and slogan2 into place on page load   
        //by assigning to divElement.style.left recursively
        slider = document.getElementById('slogan1');
        slider.style.left = '5%';
        slider = document.getElementById('slogan2');
        slider.style.left = '50%';
    }               
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="slogan" id="slogan1">Some
    <div id="rep1">
        <p>Some copy that represents parent slogan ipso lorum 1234567890 2345 7890 234567890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890</p>
        <p>More copy that represents parent slogan ipso lorum 1234567890 2345 7890 234567890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890?</p>
        <p>More copy that represents parent slogan ipso lorum 1234567890 2345 7890 234567890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890!</p>
    </div>
</div>          
<div class="slogan" id="slogan2">Slogan
    <div id="rep2">
        <p>Some copy that represents parent slogan ipso lorum 1234567890 2345 7890 234567890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890</p>
        <p>More copy that represents parent slogan ipso lorum 1234567890 2345 7890 234567890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890?</p>
        <p>More copy that represents parent slogan ipso lorum 1234567890 2345 7890 234567890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890 2345 7890!</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.. its exactly why position absolute should be avoided whenever possible.

Position absolute means pixel fixed at a certain location.. if you resize your window the elements will keep the location you give them, if that means they will overlap, thats what they will do.

If you want your content to adjust to screen size, use floating elements instead of absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: I'm looking at modifying the position property to 'static' at the end of the page load script.  It does some interesting things, the most important of which is each element is now block level.

Comment: Yes, modifying both sliders to static, and making sure 'float: left' is in the slogan class block, seems to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Good that i could put you on the right path. Be sure to accept the answer if it helped though.